# Horizontal timeline with liquid syntax and slick js

Tags: javascript, css, liquid, slick.js

This horizontal timeline that I'm trying to achieve is using liquid syntax and slick js.

Here's my code to list out the timeline:

```
{% assign alltimeline = all_testimonials | articles_with_tag: "timeline" %}
{% assign alltimeline_sort = alltimeline | sort: 'sub_title' %}

<ul class="timeline d-flex flex-column">
   {% for timeline in alltimeline_sort %}
     <li>
        {{ timeline.sub_title }} //year
        {{ timeline.title }} //timeline title
        {{ timeline.body }} //timeline body
     </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However, this code will print out all item along with the year for each - something like this:

2008

Title One

Timeline Description One

2008 

Title Two

Timeline Description Two

2008 

Title Three

Timeline Description Three

2019 

Title Four

Timeline Description Four

2019

Title Five

Timeline Description Five

However, what I'm trying to achieve is to display the year first, and then the item that is tagged under that year - something like this:

**2008**

Title One

Timeline Description One

Title Two

Timeline Description Two

Title Three

Timeline Description Three

**2019**

Title Four

Timeline Description Four

Title Five

Timeline Description Five

Below is the image that I'm trying to achieve

[image: I'm trying to achieve this timeline design]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to check for a repeating year:

```
{% assign alltimeline = all_testimonials | articles_with_tag: "timeline" %}
{% assign alltimeline_sort = alltimeline | sort: 'sub_title' %}

<ul class="timeline d-flex flex-column">
   {% for timeline in alltimeline_sort %}
     <li>
        {% if lastsubtitle != timeline.sub_title %}
          {{ timeline.sub_title }}
        {% endif %}
        {{ timeline.title }}
        {{ timeline.body }}
     </li>
     {% assign lastsubtitle = timeline.sub_title %}
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```